# How to integrate this lib/component in my react-native android project?

Tags: react-native

I'm a new to react-native world. How to integrate this lib/component([react-native-chart-android](https://github.com/hongyin163/react-native-chart-android)) in my react-native android project? It seems his example doesn't work on my local project.

I don't know how to add below code in my local android project. I'm using the latest react-native version. there is no place let me register module like what he did(Register Module in MainActivity.java section). I added this line in my MainApplication.java

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
          new MPChartPackage()// <------ add this line to yout 
  );
}
```

};

And then I copied LineChart.android.js, Button.js, TitleBar.js and LineChart.js into the same level with index.android.js

I also added some js code in my index.android.js like this:

```
    import LineChart from './LineChart'
    const ROUTES = {
      lineChart:LineChart
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'lineChart'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
        configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}/>
    );
  }
}
```

I run my android app on my device, and I found blank page on my device with any exception or error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to copy the js files anywhere. Assuming you completed the gradle changes and MainApplication.java changes (yes, it is in a different place then his example because that just recently changed) you should be able to just do this:

```
import { BarChart } from 'react-native-chart-android';

{...}

render() {
    return (
        <BarChart style={{flex: 1}} data={this.getDate()} />
    );
}

{...}
```

getData is assumed to just be the method from the example provided on the github page.